# Ruby operator method calls vs. normal method calls

Tags: ruby, syntax, methods

I'm wondering why calls to operator methods don't require a dot? Or rather, why can't normal methods be called without a dot?

Example

```
class Foo
  def +(object)
    puts "this will work"
  end
  def plus(object)
    puts "this won't"
  end
end 
f = Foo.new
f + "anything" # "this will work"
f plus "anything" # NoMethodError: undefined method `plus' for main:Object
```

Comment: If you want to try a cool language that doesn't use dots for method invocations, check out [Io](http://www.iolanguage.com/), which "has no keywords or statements ... [everything is an expression composed entirely of messages, each of which is a runtime accessible object](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Syntax)".It not only lets you add new operators at runtime, it even lets you change operator precedence at runtime if you like. (!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation doesn't have the additional complexity that would be needed to allow generic definition of new operators.

Instead, Ruby has a Yacc parser that uses a statically defined grammar. You get the built-in operators and that's it. Symbols occur in a fixed set of sentences in the grammar. As you have noted, the operators *can* be overloaded, which is more than most languages offer.

Certainly it's not because Matz was lazy.

Ruby actually has a fiendishly complex grammar that is roughly at the limit of what can be accomplished in Yacc.  To get more complex would require using a less portable compiler generator or it would have required writing the parser by hand in C, and doing *that* would have limited future implementation portability in its own way as well as not providing the world with the Yacc input. That would be a problem because Ruby's Yacc source code is the only Ruby grammar documentation and is therefore "the standard".

Answer (score 12):

The answer to this question, as to pretty much *every* language design question is: "Just because". Language design is a series of mostly subjective trade-offs. And for most of those subjective trade-offs, the *only* correct answer to the question why something is the way it is, is simply "because Matz said so".

There are certainly other choices:

- Lisp doesn't have operators *at all*. `+`, `-`, `::`, `>`, `=` and so on are simply normal legal function names (variable names, actually), just like `foo` or `bar?`

  ```
  (plus 1 2)
  (+ 1 2)
  ```
- Smalltalk *almost* doesn't have operators. The only special casing Smalltalk has is that methods which consist only of operator characters do not have to end with a colon. In particular, since there are no operators, all method calls have the same precedence and are evaluated strictly left-to-right: `2 + 3 * 4` is `20`, not `14`.

  ```
  1 plus: 2
  1 + 2
  ```
- Scala *almost* doesn't have operators. Just like Lisp and Smalltalk, `*`, `-`, `#:::` and so on are simply legal method names. (Actually, they are also legal class, trait, type and field names.) *Any* method can be called either with or without a dot. If you use the form without the dot and the method takes only a single argument, then you can leave off the brackets as well. Scala *does* have precedence, though, although it is not user-definable; it is simply determined by the first character of the name. As an added twist, operator method names that end with a colon are inverted or right-associative, i.e. `a :: b` is equivalent to `b.::(a)` and not `a.::(b)`.

  ```
  1.plus(2)
  1 plus(2)
  1 plus 2
  1.+(2)
  1 +(2)
  1 + 2
  ```
- In Haskell, any function whose name consists of operator symbols is considered an operator. Any function can be treated as an operator by enclosing it in backticks and any operator can be treated as a function by enclosing it in brackets. In addition, the programmer can freely define associativity, fixity and precedence for user-defined operators.

  ```
  plus 1 2
  1 `plus` 2
  (+) 1 2
  1 + 2
  ```

There is no particular reason why Ruby couldn't support user-defined operators in a style similar to Scala. There *is* a reason why Ruby can't support arbitrary methods in operator position, simply because

```
foo plus bar
```

is *already* legal, and thus this would be a backwards-incompatible change.

Another thing to consider is that Ruby wasn't actually fully designed in advance. It was designed through its implementation. Which means that in a lot of places, the implementation is leaking through. For example, there is absolutely no logical reason why

```
puts(!true)
```

is legal but

```
puts(not true)
```

isn't. The only reason *why* this is so, is because Matz used an LALR(1) parser to parse a non-LALR(1) language. If he had designed the language *first*, he would have never picked an LALR(1) parser in the first place, and the expression would be legal.

The `Refinement` feature currently being discussed on `ruby-core` is another example. The way it is currently specified, will make it *impossible* to optimize method calls and inline methods, *even if the program in question doesn't actually use `Refinement`s at all*. With just a simple tweak, it can be just as expressive and powerful, *and* ensure that the pessimization cost is only incurred for scopes that actually *use* `Refinement`s. Apparently, the sole reason *why* it was specified this way, is that a) it was easier to prototype this way, and b) YARV doesn't *have* an optimizer, so nobody even bothered to think about the implications (well, nobody except Charles Oliver Nutter).

So, for basically *any* question you have about Ruby's design, the answer will almost always be either "because Matz said so" or "because in 1993 it was easier to implement that way".

Comment: Is it normal for languages to be designed first, then implemented?

Comment: What is "normal"? It's certainly not "abnormal". All of Niklaus Wirth's languages were designed first. Algol was designed first. Lisp was designed first. In fact, John McCarthy designed it as a convenient notation for mathematical proofs, he didn't even think it was *possible* to implement it! He even *told* his student, who realized that it *could* be implemented that he was wrong! APL was invented as a notation for teaching mathematics and only implemented much later. Scheme was designed first. ML was designed *and proven correct* first. FP was designed first and actually never implemented!

Comment: +1 First of all, thank you for the very in depth and informative answer. I realize that `foo plus bar` is legal, I guess I was thinking more of a haskellish function application: `(+) 1 2` , but in a more rubish way; maybe it would be better as `foo (plus) bar`. Also "2 + 3 * 4 is 20, not 24.", do you mean "not 14"? :P

Answer (score 3):

Because Ruby has "syntax sugar" that allows for a variety of convenient syntax for preset situations. For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar=( o ); end
end

# This is actually calling the bar= method with a parameter, not assigning a value
Foo.new.bar = 42
```

Here's a list of the [operator expressions](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html%23operatorexpressions) that may be implemented as methods in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Because Ruby's syntax was designed to look roughly like popular OO languages, and those use the dot operator to call methods. The language it borrowed its object model from, Smalltalk, didn't use dots for messages, and in fact had a fairly "weird" syntax that many people found off-putting. Ruby has been called "Smalltalk with an Algol syntax," where Algol is the language that gave us the conventions you're talking about here. (Of course, there are actually more differences than just the Algol syntax.)

Comment: So is this just a stylistic design choice or is there performance concerns when the code is interpreted? (Does it inherently take longer to unify methods without dots preceding them)

Comment: Good questions .. as it happens Ruby is already pushing the limits of what can be done in Yacc. I've elaborated a bit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing braces was some "advantage" for ruby 1.8, but with ruby 1.9 you can't even write `method_0 method_1 some param` it will be rejected, so the language goes rather to the strict version instead of freeforms.

Comment: Ahh, works for me in 1.9:   irb(main):002:0> def f x; 'f' + x.to_s; end; f f 'q'
=> "ffq"

Comment: just rechecked some combinations and it seams they did not include it in ruby 1.9 (there was plan for it as I remember)

Comment: At one point, it was planned to disallow prose mode in Ruby 2.0, but that plan was abandoned at least 5 years ago.