# Ruby Assignment Operators

Tags: ruby

Why is the addition "operator" a method while the assignment operator `+=` not?

Why do operators work this way:

```
ruby-head > 2.+(4)  
# => 6
```

While assignment operators work this way:

```
ruby-head > i = 1  
# => 1  
ruby-head > i += 1  
# => 2  
ruby-head > i.+=(1) 
# SyntaxError: (irb):26: syntax error,
# unexpected '=' i.+=(1)
#                   ^  from /Users/fogonthedowns/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/irb:17:in
# > `<main>'
```

Comment: Interesting. How would += react to a reimplementation of '+' operator? Perhaps '+=' is merely syntactic sugar for assigning the variable to the result of variable.+(some value).

Comment: This is almost duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360810/ruby-operator-method-calls-vs-normal-method-calls

Comment: Your question is, "Why is this thing designed as it is?" Do you expect any answer other than "Because the language designer decided it is so?" Are you hoping that Matz himself will come explain his design rationale?

Comment: @Phrogz: Actually, there is a better answer than that, and sepp2k gave it.

Comment: @JZ I apologize if I seemed unchill. My point was not to be cranky, but to help you to reflect upon what you really wanted to know. @Chuck sepp2k's point starts with "Because", and is reasonable, but it isn't really an explanation. It simply points out another part of the language that would have to be changed if this behavior were not so. The answer, IMHO, is "Because Matz designed it this way, and it happens to work well with other aspects of the language." *shrug* Questions like this seem typically to be a forum for someone to suggest that they disagree with a design.

Comment: Perhaps I am being too literal with the question form. Perhaps it is generally understood that questions of "Why is _this_ as it is?" are actually "Please explain the consequences if we changed _this_ to something else."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because assignment works on variables not objects and thus cannot be implemented as a method.

Comment: Or more fundamentally: because variables aren't objects. If they *were*, one could just implement `=` as a method on variables.

Comment: So much for Ruby being objects all the way down :(

Answer (score 2):

The += is (as I conjectured) syntactic sugar that uses the + method. If you subclass or monkey-patch a class to change the behaviour of +:

```
class CustomPlus
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
  def +(other)
    value + other * 2
  end
end
```

Then the result is this:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > a = CustomPlus.new(2)
 => #<CustomPlus:0x000001009eaab0 @value=2> 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > a.value
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > a+=2
 => 6
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `def +=(other)` instead of `def +(other)`? Or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: The += operator implies the + operator. It uses that, then assigned the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because `+=` is just a shorthand for the full expression.

If it were a message of its own, then adding operator behavior for a class would require defining an assignment operator for each of the shorthand combinations, in addition to the already-probably-required operators for plain assignment and each binary operator.

It's hard to imagine what would be gained for all that extra work, so Ruby treats the combined assignment operators simply as shorthand for the full expression.

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem. All the assignment operators could just be defined on `Object` (e.g. something like `def +=(o) self = self + o end`, which would still cause a `NoMethodError` when used with an object which does not respond to `+` and give the desired behaviour for objects that do - except that it does not work of course). The problem is rather that you can't define assignment operators as methods because you can't define methods that work on variables.